# Speed API Event / Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

In most of my cases I'd like to use the API Event since we could directly use it in a Journey. I've set up a test Journey with API Event as entry source and just one Activity, that would send an Email with high priority immidiatly. However, compared with a triggered send which is send instantly (up to 30secs), the API Event seems to take up to 5-10 mostly.

Is this a common behaviour that API Events take much longer then triggered send or could it be related to something in our system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important thing regarding speed is the priority set in your email activity. If this is set to high I definitely got faster email deliveries than in your test. The journey delivery duration was roughly the same as for triggered sends (or just some seconds slower). In tests I performed some time ago I got the following results (measured from the time the trigger is fired until the email notification from google mail arrived):

**API-Triggered journey with E-Mail send activity (average of several test runs):**

- Priority High: ~15s
- Priority Medium: ~2m
- Priority Low: ~6m 20s

**Triggered send (average of several test runs):**

- Priority High: ~11s
- Priority Medium: ~1m 30s

**EDIT:**
As Eliot mentioned, sending with high priority costs 4 super messages instead of one. Further information can be found in the [Marketing Cloud Super Message Bundles document](https://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/marketing_cloud_super_message_bundles.pdf).

**EDIT "Transactional Messaging API":**
Recently Salesforce launched the Transactional Messaging API which is even faster than triggered sends with high priority. And another benefit is, that you don't have to waste so much super messages, as every send is only counted as a single supermessage. However, the downside is, that you cannot configure the messages via a user interface and have to do it via the API as well.

Further information: [Transactional Messaging API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm)

Comment: **Important note:** messages sent with a high priority count as **four** Super Messages — yes that's right, they cost **four times** as much a regular triggered Email. Refer to [this document](https://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/marketing_cloud_super_message_bundles.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! Forgot to mention that as it was so clear to me. Updated my answer to be more complete, so it includes all the information needed even for users who are less experienced.